# How to do conditional compare in pandas like this?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'name':['Alice','Bob','Cindy','Eric','Helen','Grace '],
                   'math':[90,89,99,78,97,93],
                   'english':[89,94,80,94,94,90]})
```

also I have i list that contain 3 names:

```py
list = ['Alice','Bob','Cindy']
```

How can I get a new Dataframe that only have 3 names like：

```
id    name    math    english
1     Alice   90      89
2     Bob     89      94
3     Cindy   99      80
```

Is it possble to achieve it with one `loc`function?

Comment: Use `df[df['name'].isin(list)]`. BTW, making a variable named same as built-in functions (`list`) will shadow it. I would highly recommend you to use something like `l`, or `my_list`, etc.